# Exchange 2013 mysterious calendar notifications

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, exchange-2013

Exchange 2013 environment, all conference rooms are setup as e-mail boxes.

There are 3 users that administer these conference rooms.  I am tasked with adding a new admin.  I have added the new user to Full Access and Sen on Behalf.  The user can now see the Inbox in their Outlook and Grant or Deny or Delete meetings.

But, the previous Admins receive notification directly in their inbox, they do not have to open the Conference Room Inbox.

When I checked the 'Delivery Options: and "Forwarding Address" box nothing is checked! Enable Forwarding is OFF. I cannot find where or how these previous Admins are receiving these notifications.

I am including the Properties of one of these notifications below:

```
Received: from SHCEMAIL.shc.shcnet.pri (172.31.100.110) by
 SHCEMAIL.shc.shcnet.pri (172.31.100.110) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id
 15.0.1365.1 via Mailbox Transport; Tue, 19 Nov 2019 11:28:17 -0500
Received: from SHCEMAIL.shc.shcnet.pri (172.31.100.110) by
 SHCEMAIL.shc.shcnet.pri (172.31.100.110) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id
 15.0.1365.1; Tue, 19 Nov 2019 11:28:17 -0500
Received: from SHCEMAIL.shc.shcnet.pri ([::1]) by SHCEMAIL.shc.shcnet.pri
 ([::1]) with mapi id 15.00.1365.000; Tue, 19 Nov 2019 11:28:17 -0500
Content-Type: application/ms-tnef; name="winmail.dat"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
From: Quincy - Boardroom <ConferenceR@shields.com>
To: Daniel Michaelis <danielm@shields.com>
Subject: FW: TEsting
Thread-Topic: TEsting
Thread-Index: AdWe9WHfn/D5gTt5RaGO+bmcLVYobAAAAPbAAAA6M5A=
Sender: Jean Jones <JEANJ@shields.com>
X-MS-Exchange-MessageSentRepresentingType: 2
Date: Tue, 19 Nov 2019 11:28:16 -0500
Message-ID: <ea4a22aab90944239bd22a29b5f59787@SHCEMAIL.shc.shcnet.pri>
References: <cbe3c34dac0b472fa326f84ef50a0c49@SHCEMAIL.shc.shcnet.pri>
In-Reply-To: <cbe3c34dac0b472fa326f84ef50a0c49@SHCEMAIL.shc.shcnet.pri>
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: -1
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: <ea4a22aab90944239bd22a29b5f59787@SHCEMAIL.shc.shcnet.pri>
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-FromEntityHeader: Hosted
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Originating
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: SHCEMAIL.shc.shcnet.pri
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Internal
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism: 04
X-Originating-IP: [172.31.53.43]
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id: 4547f261-8628-4d37-2eec-08d76d0d7bba
Return-Path: JEANJ@shields.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AVStamp-Enterprise: 1.0
```

I need the New Admin to receive the same notifications directly into their inbox without opening the Conference Room inbox.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to ask..

Comment: I Apologize, this is very confusing.I need to add a new conference room admin to our system but cannot enable her to receive notifications in her InBox from the mailboxes she has permissions to administer.  I have looked in the normal places for E-Mail forwarding but these are not even enabled at the mailbox delivery options window.  I need to find out how the notifications are being delivered so I can add this new user to the notification process